# Client side validation and server side validation

Tags: asp.net, validation

Why do we need both client side and server side validation ? i have read that both are necessary for security reasons.. so if client side validation can be bypass then why not use only server side..what is the use of using client side..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important for users with slow/restricted/limited internet connection to avoid unnecessary request to the server (e.g. request to submit a form containing invalid data, which will eventually get rejected by the server). The waiting time for the response may become a reason for a user to leave your web page, and then talk bad about your web site to friends and relatives, or even to whoever.

We always want to make all users happy, don't we (even though sometimes we feel that they are the enemy)

Answer (score 1):

Client side validation helps the user to correct the errors without a full postback with all error messages in it. It enhances efficiency, but its just a convenience and can obviously be bypassed.

Comment: thnx..thats helps me in understanding client side validation..i more simple question..does all validation done using javascript is client side?

Answer (score 1):

it's not good practice postback for every validation so you will need to put client side validation to validate fields which are mandatory so you should put client side validation also

About Server side validation, you cant realy compltetly on client side in case browser javascript disabled it is better to be validated at server side.

Answer (score 1):

With client-side rendering, your initial request loads the page layout, CSS and JavaScript. It's all common except that some or all of the content isn't included. Instead, the JavaScript makes another request, gets a response (likely in JSON), and generates the appropriate HTML (likely using a templating library).For subsequent updates to the page, the client-side rendering approach repeats the steps it used to get the initial content. Namely, JavaScript is used to get some JSON data and templating is used to create the HTML.

Updates using server-side rendering is where a lot of developers start going off the deep end. They actually think page refresh

Answer (score 1):

Both client-side and server-side are needed for many reasons. i am writing few points that will explain why it is necessary

- for every from validation a request sent from web browser to the web server. so it is a unnecessary overhead to the server for checking every control to validate. suppose 1,00,000 people sending the same request to the server. For every request and response it will take some time(may be in nano seconds) which is really unnecessary. so it is recommended to use client-side validation.
- For security reason we must use the server-side validation. As a programmer it is responsible to stop the bad data coming to our application. suppose in browser someone intentionally or by unknowingly disable the JavaScript and trying to insert the data. if server-side validation is not present there bad data can come to our application. Data may be some wrong information or it can be a self executed program also which is really harmful for our application.

so it is recommended to use both client-side and server-side validation for a better standard application.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need client side, but it's much more convenient for the user if a post-back isn't necessary. If you don't care about the UX, you can make all of your validators server-side only and your data and operations will be protected.